# How can I customize a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, customization

I need to customize a gem. I am using Jruby and use warbler to build a war file to deploy app. I need to customize some ssl options for Rest Client gem. How can I customize any gem?

Answer (score 1):

- Fork the gem on github (or wherever it is hosted)
- Make modifications to your fork of the gem
- Change your `Gemfile` to point the gem to your new git repo (gem 'gem-name', git: 'git repo url')
- bundle
- commit the changes to `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`
- deploy